# Jquery/WP plugin to slurp meta like Google, Facebook, Linkedin by simply paste an url?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins

You know, when you paste an url, these famous services can display both title, meta and an image, do you know any jquery plugin or wordpress plugin that does the same?

Thx a lot for your assistance,

Isabelle,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called [microdata](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=176035). Unfortunately it seems there aren't any plugins to make microdata parsing easy on Wordpress, but that doesn't mean you can't use a PHP or JavaScript tool to do it.

There's [microdatajs](https://gitorious.org/microdatajs/) for JavaScript and [PHP-Microdata](https://github.com/soyrex/PHP-Microdata) for PHP from a quick Google Search.

[schema.org](http://schema.org) can give you an idea of what these microdata tags look like.